# React Redux Search Reducer

Tags: redux, react-redux

Currently I have the below reducer switch statement. All it does is toggles the state of Sidebar, so first it shows then hides then shows. It's easy.

```
switch(action.type) {
      case 'SIDEBAR_DISPLAY_TOGGLE':
    return {
      ...state,
      Sidebar : {
        ...state.Sidebar,
        Display : !state.Sidebar.Display
      }
    }
      default:
        return state;
    }
```

Now I have a input field like here
[image]

that people can type to search account. I am trying to set up Redux so when user types, it gets saved to the Redux global state and I can pull it from another component. I have this reducer code set up for it but I don't know how can I pull what user types into this reducer from that component?

```
 function reducer(state = initialState, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
      case 'ACCOUNT_SEARCH':
        return {
          ...state,
          AccountNumberSearch : {
            ...state.AccountNumberSearch,
            AccountNumber : ''
          }
        }
      default:
        return state;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: a convention is to put the value in `action.payload` but that depends on what your action does and how you call/dispach it. Please post the relevant code. Also keep in mind that using the redux store for each keystroke might be overkill. You might want to use the local state to control the field and either debounce the storing to the redux store or store it after some additional user action like pressing a button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An action is just an object with a string value named `type`. Any other properties on this object will also be passed, so you use this to pass the typed text.

If you're using a function to create your actions, something along the lines of:

```
export function accountNumberSearch(accountNumber) {
    return { type: 'ACCOUNT_SEARCH', accountNumber };
}
```

Then in your reducer, you'll be able to assign the value in the state to action.accountNumber.

```
      AccountNumberSearch : {
        ...state.AccountNumberSearch,
        AccountNumber : action.accountNumber,
      }
```

Then you can map your state to props as you normally would (as you did for the sidebar toggle).

Also, as an aside, you should look into modularising your reducers with `combineReducers` - [Docs](https://redux.js.org/api/combinereducers)
This would be much easier than the way you're doing it.

---

**EDIT: Handling the changes**

First of all, you'd want to wire up your input field for the search box to an onChange listener. If you do this like `onChange={this.onSearchChange}` you can get the value from `event` in the function:

```
onSearchChange = event => {
    this.props.AccountNumberSearch(event.target.value);
}
```

Then in `mapDispatchToProps` you'd send your action + the passed value to dispatch:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        AccountNumberSearch: AccountNumber => dispatch(importedActions.AccountNumberSearch(AccountNumber)),
    }
}
```

Then, in the component you want to RECEIVE this value, you'd map the redux state to props, like:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        AccountNumber: state.AccountNumberSearch.AccountNumber,
    }
}
```

Then you can access that value in your render function by calling `this.props.AccountNumber`.

If you need to do something when this value changes, you can always listen on `componentDidUpdate`, and compare the value with the old one - if it changed, call whatever function that you need to do.

Comment: how can I send the changes to `accountNumberSearch` action? I had this action `export const AccountNumberSearch = () => ({ type: "ACCOUNT_NUMBER_SEARCH" });` which I updated to `export const AccountNumberSearch = (accountNumber) => ({ type: "ACCOUNT_NUMBER_SEARCH", accountNumber });` and added this to reducer `AccountNumber : action.accountNumber,` but don't know how can I get it updated as user types to the input field on the page?

Comment: so on your `mapStateToProps` of your other component that you want to receive the update, you'd map `state.AccountNumberSearch.AccountNumber` to a prop, like
`AccountNumber: state.AccountNumberSearch.AccountNumber,`

Comment: you can then even listen to changes on `componentDidUpdate` on that component, by wrapping it in `if (prevProps.AccountNumber !== this.props.AccountNumber && this.props.AccountNumber !== null) { ... }` in there, you could call another action like an API action, to fetch the results, for example.

Comment: okay and I have this for the input field `value: AccountNumber,     onChange: this.updateAccountNumber('AccountNumber'), `now input field gets loaded with what I typed in default to the redux store but I can't change it... this is `update function updateAccountNumber = name => (event, { newValue }) => {AccountNumberSearch(event.target.value) }`

Comment: you can't just call the action, that'll just return an object. You need to pass the object into dispatch(...) either from your store, or from `mapDispatchToProps`

Comment: Gotcha I added that too still same `const mapDispatchToProps = { AccountNumberSearch } export default compose( withStyles(styles, { withTheme: true }), connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps), )(AccountSearch);`

Comment: @Extelliqent I've updated my answer to explain how to tie it all together.

Comment: Thank you @Jamie, everything  except 4th code box I applied that one gives error on `importedActions`... Currently this is what I have in terms of map to state, map to props and export `function mapStateToProps(state) { return { AccountNumber: state.AccountNumberSearch.AccountNumber, } } const mapDispatchToProps = { AccountNumberSearch } export default compose( withStyles(styles, { withTheme: true }), connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps), )(AccountSearch);`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190939/discussion-between-jamie-fenrir-digital-ltd-and-extelliqent).

Comment: I am thinking there's a problem with my reducer, I made changes to it, whatever I do, I don't cause dispatcher to go through this section of the reducer `switch(action.type) { case 'ACCOUNT_NUMBER_SEARCH': return { ...state, AccountNumberSearch : { ...state.AccountNumberSearch, AccountNumber : action.accountNumber, } }` and action is this `export const AccountNumberSearch = (accountNumber) => ({ type: "ACCOUNT_NUMBER_SEARCH", accountNumber: accountNumber  });`